# JQuery Load not working as hoped with A Href (But works fine with Button)

Tags: jquery, href

```
<a id="test">Interfaces</a>
```

```
<div id="include"></div>
```

```
$('#test').click(function() {
    $('#include').load("<?php echo $root; ?>/documentation/test.php")
});
```

The above works fine and loads the page from the folder, and inserts it into the HTML tag with ID equal to 'include'

I have used Cursor: Pointer in the CSS. Can anybody tell me why I should even use `<a>` tag for this function - And does it matter that I am not using 'href'? Does it make any difference if I just use `<li>` tags and no `<a>` tag whatsoever? The jQuery Load function DOESN'T WORK if I use the href="". Can anybody explain what is going on there?

Comment: If you use an `href` attribute, the browser is programmed to go to the location mentioned in the `href` attribute. That's the whole purpose of the anchor element with an `href`.

Comment: If you don't want users to navigate somewhere else (on the current page or to another page or website), then don't use an anchor element.

Comment: What about Spiders - Would they 'click' on a li tag.. But they would 'click' on the a tag and load that page?

Comment: Not familiar with Spiders... Use an anchor element, don't use an anchor element, it's not like there are police that will throw you in jail for using the wrong element. I'm just telling you what the spec says the element is for. A `button` may be more suited to what you want to do, but it has its own quirks. Nothing inherently wrong with making an `li` clickable.